# Make 24 and 30 using the digits 3 and 4

Tags: calculation-puzzle, formation-of-numbers

First, write an expression using exactly one 3 and exactly one 4 to make 24.

Second, write an expression using exactly one 3 and exactly one 4 to make 30.

### Math You Can Use for each problem:

- Division
- Factorials (just for regular factorial use, no special factorials)
- Parentheses (They would be required to show the factorial of a factorial,
  as in (X!)!, for instance.)

### Other Rules For Clarification:

- No other digits may be used.
- No other operations may be used.

I am intending one solution for each problem.

Comment: I think this puzzle would have been more interesting with a larger space of possibilities. With two numbers, a unary operator, and a binary operator, the only possible solutions take the factorial of 3 some number of times (possibly zero), likewise for 4, and divide the results. It's straightforward to write out all the small possibilities.

Answer (score 8):

30:

> $(3!)!\div4! = 30$

24:

> $(4!\div3!)! = 24$

Answer (score -1):

## Shamelessly stolen from Tim!!

24:

> $\frac{4!}{3!}!$

Cheating way:

> $3!4$

30:

> $\frac{3!!}{4!}$

More clearly:

> $\frac{(3!)!}{4!}$